# IAP test requires verification

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

when testing IAP, I click a product, which always alert me for verification.
Test user was sandbox test user created by iTunes connect and never used,
the iTunes store in device was log out, here is screen shot
[image]

Comment: There are discussions on the apple developer forums where people are reporting the same problem. Supposedly, apple is aware of the problem and is working on it.

Comment: is there a link? still get error..

Comment: If you search for "sandbox" on the apple developer forums, and sort the results by most recent, you should see relevant discussions. The following is the first result. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/206476